# Open location in Gnome Maps from command line

Tags: terminal, gnome

Is it possible to open the Gnome maps app from command line and adding a location to it, so it directly jumps to it, after opening the app?
I'm able to open the app in the command line already:

```
gnome-maps
```

I would like to do it like this:

```
gnome-maps 51.471882 58.440702
```

Is there a way I can do this?
Also, can I add more parameters, so for example it changes from regular to satellite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:
`gnome-maps` relies on *Geoclue* API
that has its own location format.

Honestly I haven't found any **official** manual/guide about it, but googling I achieve a working format:
`$ gnome-maps "geo:41.8937,12.4829;crs=wgs84;u=0"`

*PS: since I haven't found any information on official gnome-maps webpage nor geoclue, I opened a bug report here **[1]** on the official issues tracker in order to have, at least a clarification about it...*

---

**[1]** https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-maps/-/issues/281

Comment: I would like to point out that the geo: format is not GeoClue's "own location format". It is a stardard URI scheme (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme) defined by the IETF, and I believe it's supported by some other applications as well…